# ViewPager in Fragment - Setup tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm familiar with nested fragments. I am using viewpager in a fragment. I have three tabs, and want them to fill width. Instead of actionbar tabs, I tried using

- SlidingTabLayout, but it doesn't fill width.
- PagerTabStrip but the look doesn't suit my requirements
- TabHost is too naive.

I'm ok to write my own tab layout if necessary but as it is heavily used, I don't think that is actually necessary. Please help me in this regard

Comment: post any code you tried !

Comment: I tried these two https://github.com/rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ViewPager-ActionBarCompat https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip Implementation is not a problem, that is why I didn't post any code. IMHO this is a design choice

Comment: first why do not you want to use actionbar tabs? second do you want me to provide you tabhost ?

Comment: Can we use actionbar tabs in a fragment? Then it solves my case.

Comment: sorry, No i made mistake and forgotten that you wanted to use it inside fragment, sorry about that, look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: Yes, you are right. FragmentTabHost is one way, but as I mentioned it is very basic. There is no swiping between tabs or indicator when swiping etc.

Comment: the last idea that i can tell is use tabhost inside that use view pager and sync both together

Comment: Hmm.. thanks.. Wish there is a better way :)